# couchbase Sync gateway fails to connect in android

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I have been trying to run a [Grocery-sync couchbase androi demo](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/GrocerySync-Android)  on Windows machine.

I have download the [Sync-Gateway](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/downloads#) from Couchbase mobile.

While running this demo I am able to insert an Item in local Cblite. But
It doesn't pull any docs from the **SyncGateway**. When I see the request on **Sync-Gateway** -

***It shows 404 no such database "grocery-sync".***

**Sync-Gateway Response:**

2016-04-18T01:32:04.612+05:30 ==== Couchbase Sync Gateway/1.2.0(83;41aa099) ====

2016-04-18T01:32:04.614+05:30 Opening db /sync_gateway as bucket "sync_gateway",
 pool "default", server

2016-04-18T01:32:04.614+05:30 Opening Walrus database sync_gateway on

2016-04-18T01:32:04.615+05:30 Using default sync function 'channel(doc.channels)
' for database "sync_gateway"

2016-04-18T01:32:04.615+05:30     Reset guest user to config

2016-04-18T01:32:04.615+05:30 Starting profile server on

2016-04-18T01:32:04.615+05:30 Starting admin server on 127.0.0.1:4985

2016-04-18T01:32:04.621+05:30 Starting server on localhost:4984 ...

2016-04-18T01:35:26.216+05:30 HTTP:  #001: GET /grocery-sync/_local/a08b05842f7f
55be5f15b12b58de0a9b10855d71

2016-04-18T01:35:26.217+05:30 HTTP:  #002: GET /grocery-sync/_local/65fae3c5d53a
75a649f38f098ba00422c70b9786

2016-04-18T01:35:26.218+05:30 HTTP: #002:     --> 404 no such database "grocery-
sync"  (1.5 ms)

2016-04-18T01:35:26.217+05:30 HTTP: #001:     --> 404 no such database "grocery-
sync"  (1.0 ms)

2016-04-18T01:35:26.296+05:30 HTTP:  #003: POST /grocery-sync/_changes

2016-04-18T01:35:26.297+05:30 HTTP: #003:     --> 404 no such database "grocery-
sync"  (0.5 ms)

2016-04-18T01:35:36.310+05:30 HTTP:  #004: POST /grocery-sync/_changes

2016-04-18T01:35:47.359+05:30 HTTP: #004:     --> 404 no such database "grocery-
sync"  (11048.9 ms)

2016-04-18T01:35:57.375+05:30 HTTP:  #005: POST /grocery-sync/_changes

2016-04-18T01:35:57.375+05:30 HTTP: #005:     --> 404 no such database "grocery-
sync"  (0.5 ms)

As **Sync-Gateway connection** is the first step to work with Couchbase. Till than I am stuck and surfing around.

Comment: We'll be needing your config.json for sync gateway and android app code to give any solutions

Answer (score 2):

From the logs, Sync Gateway has created a database called `sync_gateway`. That's the default database name (typically when starting Sync Gateway without a config file). You can provide the database name as a [command line argument](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/guides/sync-gateway/configuring-sync-gateway/command-line-options/index.html):

```
~/Downloads/couchbase-sync-gateway/bin/sync_gateway -dbname="grocery-sync"
```

For more configuration option, you can create a config file (read more at http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/guides/sync-gateway/configuring-sync-gateway/config-properties/index.html)